# How to play all songs listed on a website?

Tags: music

How can an online music provider (eg Grooveshark) be induced or instructed to play all songs listed on a website, like Billboard: http://www.billboard.com/charts/year-end/2012/hot-adult-contemporary-songs?

I do see the “Play entire chart” button, but it only features Rdio, whereas I want to try this with other music streamers.

The laborious solution is to copy and paste each song title from Billboard's website into YouTube or Grooveshark or the like, but I want to avoid this repetitive, unproductive drudgery.

**Supplementary:** I don't know any programming or computer science.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how familiar you are with programming but without knowing more about the particular site, I would say that this is the road you would need to go down.

If you are really committed to this, I would suggest:

1. Using a tool like [Scraperwiki](https://scraperwiki.com/) to collect all the songs and titles
2. Inside your scraperwiki project, use the [YouTube Search API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search) to find a youtube link to each of the songs
3. Again, use the Google API to insert each song into a playlist.
4. Then, of course, you can just listen to your youtube playlist!

This is obviously not for everyone and I am open to other, simpler answers but this is the only way that I am aware of.

If you have any issues, stackoverflow.com is the place to try!

Of course, you needn't do it yourself. If you don't have the time to learn programming and you are willing to pay for it, there are plenty of freelance sites where you can offer $20/30 for someone to set something like I have described up for you... That's always an option.

Comment: An alternative to using the Google Search API for the youtube link is to use the Grooveshark API and [add the songs to a playlist](http://developers.grooveshark.com/docs/public_api/v3/#setPlaylistSongs).

Comment: +1: Thanks. The bounty and grace period seem to have vanished; I've asked the moderators to award it to you.

Comment: @LePressentiment The answer must have a score of +2 or above to be auto-awarded.  Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work for details.  Moderators cannot award a bounty to a user.